# Codeigniter routing issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, uri

I am customizing my routes in codeigniter, here is a sample of my routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'maincontroller/main';                                                                                                                                                                                    
$route['404_override'] = '';     

$route['test'] = 'maincontroller/test';
```

here is the maincontroller class:

```
class Maincontroller extends CI_Controller  
{                 
    public function __construct( )
    {
        parent::__construct( ); 
        $this->load->library('session');  
        $this->init( ); 
    }


    public function main( )         
    {       
        echo "in main";
    } 

    public function test( )
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

but when i access this url in my browser: /test, i get the server's 404 page not found error.

I have no idea what im doing wrong, i followed the routes guide in codeigniter user guide.

Comment: wow that worked....thanks.  So how do i set the routes so that it always includes the index.php in the url, like by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of going to /test , try going to /index.php/test

By default CodeIgniter runs everything through index.php.

You can change this behaviour by adding a .htaccess file to the site root folder.

This is taken straight from the CodeIgniter user guide.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

The htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you do this you also need to change your config/config.php file

find

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

change it to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

When you want to create links in a page (view) you can use the built in site_url() function, you may need to load the url helper for this.

for example

```
<?php echo site_url('test'); ?>
```

This will take into account the $config['index_page'] setting and create the right url for your link.

Comment: wow that worked....thanks. So how do i set the routes so that it always includes the index.php in the url, like by default.

Comment: Cheers :) hope this info helps, please check the link I added to get the best info on CodeIgniter URLs

Comment: You don't need to worry about adding index.php to the routes, you use a combination of the url helper and site_url function to create the correct links in your views / pages.

Comment: can you provide me commands for the .htaccess file when my codeigniter site is in a sub folder, ie www.root.com/codeigniterfolder  ? thanks

Comment: let me test something quick and ill get back to you

Comment: Try changing the last line in the htaccess file to this
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: I have removed the / from infront of index.php

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to run your site from localhost use the below code..
adding a .htaccess file to the site root folder (e.g: mysite).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /root folder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

for the site hosted on the remote hosting server, use this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```