# How do I fix the routes in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

I have some issues with Routes in CI. also new with this framework. I want to ask you guys, (I have read similar example with my problem but it doesn't work for me).

(the link)
[Codeigniter routing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166054/codeigniter-routing-issues)

every time I want to link another page in main page. CI said:![error routes][1]

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

when i access this url in my browser: /test, i get the error routes. 
here is a sample of my routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "frontline";
$route['404_override'] = 'error404';
$route['test'] = 'frontline/test';
```

and this my controller:

```
class Frontline extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index.php');
    }

    public function test(){
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of codeigniter v2.x or v3.x?

Comment: check your controller file name